# Change main layout from Recycler item button click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have this problem when I have to set the visibility of layout from Recycler item button click. How can I change "some other layout" params from RecyclerAdapter onBindViewHolder method?
[image: Example of situation]

Comment: can you share your `recycler-adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I passed the view to the constructor and then I was able to change its visibility and etc...
like

```
> mAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<someobject> arrayList, RelativeLayout
> weblayout, WebView web, ProgressBar progressBar, RecyclerView
> listView) { this.weblayout; this.web; this.progressBar; tihs.listview;
> ...
```